# Why do all of my browsers redirect me to IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

In my browser, when I punch in any address, it takes me to a strange blue background page with a big "IIS7" in the middle and "welcome" in many different languages around it.  It sounds like I have to go through this page to get to any web address.  It happens in all of my browsers including Internet Explorer and Google Chrome

Also, when I go to a website by `https` and when I am in the middle of working with it, I sometimes receive an error message saying:

> IIS7 detailed error 404; HTTP error 404

I have screen shots of this problem but I don't know how to attach it.  I am scared my laptop is hacked.  I ran Malwarebytes but still have this problem.

Comment: just post the images up somewhere - http://imgur.com/ works, and someone with sufficient reputation will edit in for you. You will also want to give some details about your OS (i'm guessing windows) and browser versions

Comment: By the way: For the future, you should rather edit your [old question](http://superuser.com/questions/366812/why-google-chrome-redirect-me-to-iis7) and have it reopened by flagging it for moderator attention.

Comment: please mention your OS (Xp, win 7 etc.) and also whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit. You can find out the information abt OS by typing `winver` in Run dialog box.

Comment: Either your `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file or your DNS servers have been compromised by the sounds of it.  Have a look in your hosts file first and see if it contains anything other than `localhost`.  Please stop using this for anything sensitive until this is worked out.

Comment: the OS is vista 64 bit. I have checked my hostsfile and it looks ok. there is nothing other than 127.0.0.1       localhost